I have a Blazor server side app with windows authentication. Can I program I custom login dialog window instead of the standard one?
I have a Blazor server side app with windows authentication. So normally when someone enters my page the standard windows login dialog of the browser appears. I think I cannot customize this window.
Is there a way to program a custom login dialog window and suppress the standard one? If yes can someone explain me the general way I have to go?
The reason why I want to do that: I want to add at least some explanation to the dialog window to which application this dialog window belongs. My app is working on a intranet server, and the user is just typing the server name and port as address when he enters my page. So in the dailog box I want to add at least the application name if possible.

You can use custom page to login user. And use advapi32.dll to replace the default windows authentication.
